# Multiple activeclassname Link in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How to make 2 active classes in nextjs?

Let's say I have a menu

I use this [ActiveLink](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/active-class-name/components/ActiveLink.tsx)

```
<div className='menu'>
  <ActiveLink href='/' activeclassname='active'></ActiveLink>
  <ActiveLink href='/users' activeclassname='active'></ActiveLink>
</div>
```

If you click on the users link there is a second submenu

```
<div className='menu2'>
  <ActiveLink href='/users' activeclassname='active'></ActiveLink>
  <ActiveLink href='/users/top' activeclassname='active'></ActiveLink>
</div>
```

ActiveLink reads the router I am currently on and makes it active. I need, if I moved from the first menu to users, and then to users/top, so that users is active in the first menu and users/top in the second

Comment: Firstly the prop is called `activeClassName`, in camel case. Secondly you can just pass two names? e.g `activeClassName="my-class other-class".`